# jQuery div class changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

`#myDiv` is a clickable box, if `#myDiv` is clicked, there is a class `.opened`  will be added. my jQuery reads

```
if ($('#myDiv').hasClass('open')){
 var myValue = "1";
}else{
 var myValue = "2";
}
```

Apparently, after the page completed loaded, `myValue` always equals 2, but after clicking `#myDiv`, `myValue` is still 2. what event should I use to detect whether my elements change? I'd like to support IE7+ as well. thanks!

Comment: you have typo.. myVaule?

Comment: did your issue got resolved due to the typo? also as per your edit.. if "opened" is your class name then hasClass('opened') should be your condition.

Comment: Block level code has no scope in itself in javascript. Avoid using var inside if. Use it outside the if block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution : http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/Emv8L/

```
function containOpen(){
  if ($('#myDiv.open').length==1){
  var myValue = "1";

  }
  else{
       var myValue = "2";
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to rerun the code, there is no way for that code to change just because a class has been added/removed.

So when the click happens you would need to call a function that will set the value.

Answer (score 0):

In your click event listener, suscribe your element a custom [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#eventdata) `$('#myDiv').trigger('openedClassAdded')`.

Then

```
$('#myDiv').on('openedClassAdded', function () {
    myValue = '2';
});
```